# how to DISABLE the cairo-dock MESSAGE about the "black background"?

Tags: cairo-dock

so, I can actually bear the black background that shows only when cairo-dock is visible, I am at JWM (and I wont change to another WM).

but... I cant bear that message everytime it is started.
[image]

is there no single option to disable tha annoying message?

the problem with it is that it requires a click to go away, if it had a timeout it would be acceptable tho.

btw, I cant find the option from the message either, here is what I got:
[image]
dbus and gnome integration are innacessible

Comment: The message says *"if your machine can't support composition, Cairo-Dock can emulate it."* Why don't you try that?

Comment: @CelticWarrior could you pin-point the exact way to reach that option? I have tried now for the 6th time to no avail... other than browsing all modules, I also type somethings on the advanced mode to filter the modules like "emulat" etc and nothing seems to bring such option... should I install some extra module? they should put a link on that popup (or clarify it) to help us..

Comment: In the popup is said *"This option is in the 'System' module of the configuration, at the bottom of the page"*. Are you saying you use the aforementioned option but the error message still appears?

Comment: @CelticWarrior, no I am saying I am unable to find such option, like as in it is not there at all, I will add a screen shot...

Comment: and when you click "more applets"?

Comment: @Rinzwind opens this page: http://www.glx-dock.org/mc_album.php?a=12 on a browser, and that option "is" builtin.